# Identifying frequency components only

Tags: fourier-transform, power-spectral-density

I have a real world system of a rotating back and forth motion and the time domain data suggests that the data is a random signal (not a deterministic signal).  I recorded discrete data points at a constant sampling rate in my lab notebook from raw data recorded by a computer program at a sampling rate where I don't have to worry about aliasing and I now wish to identify the frequency components in the oscillations.  I don't care about power or intensities of the frequencies contained, I just want the identity of the present frequencies themselves.

1. For the above goal, is it sufficient to simply take the Fourier transform (fast Fourier transform) of my time domain data?
2. If it is not sufficient to simply take the Fourier transform to identify the frequencies, what do I need to do to my fast Fourier transform output/data from my software (I have numerical data of peak intensity vs. frequency) in order to obtain a power spectral density (which does tell frequency intensities, but again, I don't care about intensities for my purposes)?  Is taking FFT data to power spectral density as simple as doing some math on each FFT vs. frequency data point?
3. As a more broad/general question, in order to identify a peak in the frequency domain as a frequency constituent, how tall must the peak be so that it isn't disregarded as part of the noise?  Is there a heuristic involved where one can begin to say that a peak is an actual frequency of the phenomenon and not part of some background noise?

Comment: You say in your lab notebook, which implies to me that you cut and pasted some small length of data, or you recorded times and intensities by hand.  Please _edit your question_ to say how long your set of points is, and if (or how close to) they are taken at a constant sampling rate.

Comment: This depends A LOT on your specific details. We would need a lot more information, what  exactly is the data (Position, velocity, acceleration, something else). how much data do you have, what frequency accuracy do you need etc. You can post a representative data file (csv would be fine) as an example

Comment: @TimWescott - Yes, I ultimately did transfer all the data I took into my (electronic) lab notebook.  It was a total of 200 data points over the scope of 200 nanoseconds and they were taken at every 1 nanosecond (constant sampling rate).  This is all the data I took and all the data that I want to use in my analysis/for my posted questions.  Also, the physical phenomenon itself was at steady state, so no interruptions (i.e. no accelerations for either faster or slower) to the rotation motions.  I hope his clarifies my scenario.

Comment: @Hilmar - The data is angle values (in degrees) versus time (in nanoseconds) for widgets rotating.  There are a total of 200 data points where data was collected at every 1 nanosecond which I know that for my system relieves me from the worry of aliasing for my phenomenon (is this what you mean by frequency accuracy?).  The 200 data points are what I wish to consider in my posted questions.  I hope this clarifies my scenario.  Unfortunately I cannot post data as it is proprietary data I'm looking at.

Comment: @LobsterMan123 1ns sample rate and 200 points gives you a frequency resolution of about 5 MHz. That's awfully fast for something physicals moving. What frequency do you expect? Is your system really moving that fast ?

Comment: @Hilmar - Yes, apparently my system is truly moving that fast (a computer program is collecting the raw data for me). Starting this work, I didn't have a particular idea about what frequencies to expect as it is a new system I am looking at. Would you please tell me how you calculated 5 MHz as the frequency resolution? Thanks!

Comment: Your sampling period, $T_s$ is 1 ns. That makes your sampling frequency $f_s = 1/T_s =  1$ GHz You have $N=200$ samples.  In the frequency domain, those samples are spread between $-f_s/2$ and $+f_s/2$ so the resolution is $1$ GHz$ / 200 = 5$ MHz. That's incredibly fast for a physical object to be oscillating.